# Vaadin Styles.css file

Tags: css, vaadin

Could you help me about **CSS** and particularly the styles.css files? 
I would want to override that style:

```
 .v-checkbox > input:checked ~ label:after 
 {
    color: $link-label-color;
 }
```

But, the generated file styles.css ignores it and adds systematically another style with: root prefix in front of it as:

```
  :root .v-checkbox > input:checked ~ label:after 
  {
         color: $link-label-color;
  }
```

I don't know where: root comes from and would want not to include it in generated styles.css file.

Could you help me? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Write this in your internal CSS -

```
.v-checkbox > input:checked ~ label:after {
           color: $link-label-color !important;
 }
```

Comment: Even better put the override style at the very end of all your stylesheets loaded, then it won't need important but will override the original selector. Of course the optimal situation is edit the original class.

Comment: I would want to do but Am not getting enough reputation. I'll do it when I'll get it. Thanks.

Comment: @bik but you are able to accept the answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work